# Converter .csv para pdf com nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tentando modificar e converter um arquivo .csv com a estrutura da imagem em anexo, mas não estou conseguindo encontrar uma solução.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível fazer isso utilizando nodejs? Eu tentei usar algumas bibliotecas como csv-converter-to-pdf-and-html, exceljs e csv-report, mas os arquivos PDF que eu já consegui gerar, não vem com a estrutura correta.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Tenha por essa lib [PDF.co](https://pdf.co/samples/pdf-co-web-api-csv-to-pdf-api-javascript-convert-csv-to-pdf-from-uploaded-file-node-js)

Comment: Mas se a estrutura não está gerando corretamente, o ideal seria melhor que vc gerasse uma tela primeiro pra depois gerar a impressão dela, daí nem precisaria que fosse um CSV, mas uma HTML mesmo, daí só usar o [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) com [autotable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf-autotable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente uma dessas bibliotecas

node-html-pdf, PhantomJS, pdfkit, pdfmake

Talvez você tenha que transformar essa informação em JSON e depois converter em PDF

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Show demais, muito obrigado!!

Comment: Realmente, pra adicionar estilizações vou ter que fazer dessa forma, mas não tinha visto essas libs. Ajudou demais!